# How to access NodePort without public IP of Node in AKS?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

According to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-multiple-node-pools#assign-a-public-ip-per-node-in-a-node-pool) of Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS), `AKS nodes don't require their own public IP addresses for communication.` So, is AKS ignoring the fact that we need the public IP address of the node to access the Kubernetes NodePort service? We can of course add the public IP of the node anyway( as stated in the document). But my concern is it seems enabling the public IP of a node is not the recommended way as per the document, so any alternative to use NodePort besides enabling the public IP of the node?

Comment: A more standard configuration uses ClusterIP services instead of NodePort, and only expose those clusterIP services through an ingress. Alternatively, using LoadBalancer service type instead of clusterIP or nodeport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AKS nodes don't require their own public IP addresses for communication.`

Correct, worker nodes communicate with each other using the instance private IP, rather than making round trips to the public network.

`...is AKS ignoring the fact that we need the public IP address of the node to access the Kubernetes NodePort service?`

You don't need public IP unless you want the NodePort to be accessible on the public network. Also, VM(s) within the same VNET can still access the NodePort using the VM private IP instead of public IP.

`...any alternative to use NodePort besides enabling the public IP of the node?`

Use `type: LoadBalancer`.